# Distributable extensions (modules) for mobile app in Adobe Flex/AIR

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, module

I am creating an mobile app in flex 4.6 which will have some default embedded content. 
I need to be able to extend this app with modules (additional content libraries) let's say up to 35MB each, the client wants these modules as separate positions(packages) on the app store. How to approach such project in Flex? Is it possible to create mobile Flex app with separately purchasable extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Copy over your assets from your Application directory to user directory or application storage directory(if you want to update them). Now use you can write a module or a native app to go and update/copy these files that your app will use.

Keep in mind your Application Directory is write only and protected well. You will not be able to go edit/delete files at least for flex. From what I understand you cannot do this with IOS on the application storage directory, Apple don't like that-

http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/tag/file-applicationstoragedirectory/

http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2010/01/api_tip_dont_abuse_fileapplica.html

You should be able to detect these files and automate whatever you need. With the user directory there is a chance that your sensitive material may be accessible to the technically savvy.

Comment: Let's say I will manage to create an separate package with extra content and manage to pass this content to the main app... somehow... But what about uninstalling such content assuming there will be more than one content module?

Comment: How about using a service which keeps who has what and using generic locations for these modules? You might be able to write something simplistic with cold fusion. Use locations like UserDirectory/moduleA and UserDirectory/moduleB and then using flex/native module extension to delete modules as needed. Have you looked at ANE? A lot of games sell extension add-ons so there isn't a question what is possible just what works for your technical requirements; and how much time and money you can spend on it. Please mark the question as correct if it helped you. Good Luck!